# Directus collections do not show as schemas in GraphQL editor

Tags: graphql, directus

Basically this is what it says -- I can for some reason not see all my collections from Directus reflected as schemas in any GraphQL editor and therefore not query these, except for just one. I am not sure what causes or caused this but would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I work for Directus and this almost certainly a permissions issue. When new collections are created, they have no read/create/edit/delete permissions - you have to enable that in the Roles & Permissions settings.